# How to solve an accessibility problem using WebFont in React?

Tags: reactjs, performance, optimization

I used WebFont to use fonts from google fonts due to poor availability. The fonts work, however using WebFont resulted in another warning:
Ensure text remains visible during webfont load
**Leverage the font-display CSS feature to ensure text is user-visible while webfonts are loading.**

I don't use anywhere font-face.Is there something I may have left out?

index.js

```
import WebFont from "webfontloader";

WebFont.load({
  google: {
    families: [
      "Montserrat:300,600",
      "sans-serif",
    ],
  },
});

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Sample tag that uses this:

```
body {
     margin: 0 auto;
     font-family: ${({ theme }) => theme.font.montserrat};
}
```